# Delphi: Calculate how big a Column should be, to cut nothing off

Tags: delphi

I want to create a StringGrid in Delphi. But if a string gets too long, the string gets cut off:

[image]

I want to see the entire String. The length of the String can change, since the user can enter text in the StringGrid himself, so I can't just set the `ColWidths` to a certain integer.

Is there a way to adjust the `ColWidths` with the largest String in the Column?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can calculate the width needed for the string in each cell using the StringGrid's canvas by calling `TextWidth`.

Here's a quick sample to demonstrate. I'm doing everything in code for simplicity - the StringGrid is set up in the form's `OnCreate`, but of course that's only for demonstration purposes. To run the sample below, create a new VCL Forms Application, drop a `TStringGrid` on the form, and add the code below. I've set it up so you can use it on any column by passing that column's index to the function `CalcColumnWidth`. The `const Padding` is to add space on the right side of the column - adjust that to whatever value suits your needs.

If the user can edit the cell contents, you'll just need to call the `CalcColumnWidth` function after that edit to recalculate the column width.

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  StringGrid1.FixedRows := 0;
  StringGrid1.FixedCols := 0;
  StringGrid1.ColCount := 2;
  StringGrid1.RowCount := 4;
  StringGrid1.ColCount := 2;
  StringGrid1.Cells[0, 0] := '1';
  StringGrid1.Cells[1, 0] := 'Some text here';
  StringGrid1.Cells[0, 1] := '2';
  StringGrid1.Cells[1, 1] := 'Some other text here';
  StringGrid1.Cells[0, 2] := '3';
  StringGrid1.Cells[1, 2] := 'A  longer string goes here';
  StringGrid1.Cells[0, 3] := '4';
  StringGrid1.Cells[1, 3] := 'Shortest';
  CalcColumnWidth(1);
end;

procedure TForm1.CalcColumnWidth(const WhichCol: Integer);
var
  i, Temp, Longest: Integer;
const
  Padding = 20;
begin
  Longest := StringGrid1.Canvas.TextWidth(StringGrid1.Cells[WhichCol, 0]);
  for i := 1 to StringGrid1.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
    Temp := StringGrid1.Canvas.TextWidth(StringGrid1.Cells[WhichCol, i]);
    if Temp > Longest then
      Longest := Temp;
  end;
  StringGrid1.ColWidths[WhichCol] := Longest + Padding;
end;
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I just replaced all "StringGrid1" with "WhichSG", so that I can still determine the StringGrid in the procedure:

`procedure CalcColumnWidth(WhichSG: TStringGrid; const WhichCol: Integer);`

Answer (score 0):

I like above code flowing is update for general

```
procedure CalcGridColumnWidth(var StringGrid:TStringGrid;const WhichCol: Integer);
var
  i, Temp, Longest: Integer;
const
  Padding = 20;
begin
  Longest := StringGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(StringGrid.Cells[WhichCol, 0]);
  for i := 1 to StringGrid.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
    Temp := StringGrid.Canvas.TextWidth(StringGrid.Cells[WhichCol, i]);
    if Temp > Longest then
      Longest := Temp;
  end;
  StringGrid.ColWidths[WhichCol] := Longest + Padding;
end;
```